# Does transition to SBAS or GBAS navigation require alignment of the intermediate segment with final segment?

Tags: iaps, sbas, gbas

I am studying how the Satellite Based Augmentation System (SBAS)  or the Ground Based Augmentation System (GBAS) affect the Instrument Approach Procedures, and I noticed that in *ICAO*'s Aircraft Operations manual (8168, Volume II) it states:

> *Part III, Section 3, Chapter 5, 5.3.1*: "General. In the intermediate approach segment any sensor can be used; however, the transition to the SBAS navigation shall be made 3.7 km (2.0 NM) prior to the FAF.
>
> *Part III, Section 3, Chapter 5, 5.3.2*: Alignment. The intermediate approach segment of an SBAS procedure shall be aligned with the final
>   approach segment.
>
> Part III, Section 3, Chapter 6, 6.3.2: "The intermediate approach segment of a GBAS procedure shall be aligned with the final approach course."

Does the above quotes imply that the intermediate segment must be aligned with the final segment 2.0NM prior to the FAF, in order for the aircraft to be able to switch to SBAS navigation?

In addition, concerning both SBAS and GBAS, I would like to make sure if the rule concerning the alignment of the intermediate segment with the final segment implies that the whole segment (each leg of the intermediate segment) has to be aligned with the final, rather than only the last leg.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen an SBAS approach that had more than one intermediate segment. In all cases, the IAF/IF is aligned and more than 2 NM from the FAF. There may be multiple IAFs that feed directly to the IAF/IF. A good example is the PSM RNAV (GPS) RWY 16:

[image: PSM GBAS Approach]

As you can see, ITAWA is aligned with PUDYE.  You can get to ITAWA via SATAN, ITAWT, or directly. Arriving directly at ITAWA requires flying the procedure hold to establish the final approach course.

GBAS (or GLS in the US) is intended as a functional replacement for ILS and as such one of the goals is that GLS mimics the behavior of an ILS. As a result, the GLS procedures are designed to be flown just like an ILS approach.

You can compare the GLS and ILS approaches to Newark Rwy 04L below:

[image: KEWR GLS RWY 04L] [image: KEWR ILS or LOC Rwy 04L]

If you compare the two, you'll see the path from the FAF HOWYA to the MAP is identical. The IFs are slightly different as the GLS IF EMBAY is a pure extension of the glide path out to 2800 elevation. The ILS path is slightly different vertically between the IF and FAF due to having to identify the IF via the DME.

Comment: Gerry thank you for the indication that SBAS approach's intermediate segment consists of one leg. I have edited the question in order to include the GBAS navigation, could you comment on that too?

Comment: @Gerry Did you use the Portsmouth approach because you thought you saw a PUDYE cat?  I did.  Hehe.

Comment: I’m just surprised someone named a waypoint SATAN

Comment: @wbeard52  IDEED.

Comment: @Gerry I think I understand now that from IF to FAF the route is a straight segment aligned with the final segment, as far as SBAS and GLS are concerned. By the way, I noticed that on ILS RWY 4L chart there is an initial segment (KILMA->HOWYA) that is not included on GLS RWY 4L chart. Any idea why this initial segment is excluded from the GLS version of the IAP?

Comment: KILMA is an intersection and an IF for the ILS/LOC approach.  Note that it's on the same radial to CRI as EMBAY.  That's because the ILS/LOC does not expect any RNAV capability.  Since the GLS approach is an RNAV procedure, it expects RNAV capability on the part of the aircraft. With an RNAV system, you don't need that IF transition.  I expect there's an RNAV SID that transitions at EMBAY.